# How to space apart retries of consumer/lambda processing of SQS message to being 10 hours apart

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I would like to understand the limits with respect to how long consumer message processing attempts can be spaced apart. For example, suppose I have the following AWS Resources

- SQS Queue (named "SQSQueueName1") w/ redrive configured to send dead letter messages to SQSQueueName1DLQ
- SQS Queue DLQ (named "SQSQueueName1DLQ")
- Lambda Function (named "LambdaName1")

If SQSQueueName1 has a redrive policy with MaxRecieveCount set to 10, how long are the attempts by the consumer to process this message spaced apart in this scenario? Is there any control I have over the duration of time between consumer attempts? For example, can I space them apart such that attempts happen within 10 hours? Or is this control completely non-existant such that all control is delegated to the negotiation between the lambda pollers and the sqs (using visibility timeout + redrive)?

Again, my goal is to see if its technically possible to control the amount of time between invocations to a set amount of time, say 10 hours. 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

SQS queues have `messageVisibilityTimeout` parameter that controls exactly what you want. It is set to a duration, with max value 12 hours. After a message is read by a consumer, the message will be invisible to anyone else for the duration of `messageVisibilityTimeout`. So if you set it to 10 hours, your message will only retried after 10 hours.

Lambda triggers is not related to this parameter at all. When you trigger a Lambda function with an SQS, Lambda does a long poll to the SQS queue, in other words *asks for new messages constantly*. However, regardless of how many requests Lambda makes to SQS, if the message is not visible, Lambda won't read it.

Comment: So if the first lambda invocation fails, and redrive maxReceiveCount set to 2 and messageVisibilityTimeout set to 10 hours, message will remain invisible for 10 hours such that the two lambda invocations would be 10 hours apart?

Comment: I may just be learning about this detail, but it sounds like if 1st lambda invocation fails, message simply remains invisible on the the queue due to lack of lambda not deleting it. The duration for the invisibilty based on messageVisibilityTimeout.

Comment: @jbooker  Dead-letter queue is only used when the messaged is received maxReceiveCount times (2 in your example). That is completely separate than messageVisibilityTimeout. If you want the messages go to DLQ and then retried 10 hours lates, than you should build a more complex mechanism. And I warn you, it's an anti-pattern. It is a good practice to use DLQ only for messages that cannot be processed with regular consumers and require manual processing.